# "Missing right parenthesis" on DEFAULT in a CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, oracle-sqldeveloper, default

In the table Aposta I want the value of CodEstadoAposta to be 0 by default whenever i insert new rows and not null but this keeps showing up in the script output:

"Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:"

Table Aposta:

```
CREATE TABLE Aposta (
CodAposta Number(10) Primary key,
data DATE default sysdate not null,
hora VARCHAR2(5) not null, 
valor Number(10,2) not null,
quotaTotal Number(10,2)  not null,
CodTipoAposta references TipoAposta(CodTipoAposta) not null,
CodEstadoAposta references EstadoAposta(CodEstadoAposta) default '0' not null
);
```

And if it's helpful, table EstadoAposta and TipoAposta:

```
CREATE TABLE EstadoAposta (
CodEstadoAposta Number(1) Primary key
  check (CodEstadoAposta in ('0','1','2')),
desc_EstadoAposta VARCHAR2(20) not null
);

CREATE TABLE TipoAposta (
CodTipoAposta Number(1) Primary key
  check (CodTipoAposta in ('0','1')),
desc_TipoAposta VARCHAR2(20) not null
);
```

EDIT:

This shows up: [default syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8UOr.png) - it has '1' after default but that was just me testing.

Comment: default of zero does not require quotes unless it is a varchar2 column

Comment: Still "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: as Schern has pointed out you need a data type for each of those columns before the word "references", my note on `'0'`is just additional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
CREATE TABLE Aposta (
    CodAposta Number(10) Primary key,
    data DATE default sysdate not null,
    hora VARCHAR2(5) not null, 
    valor Number(10,2) not null,
    quotaTotal Number(10,2)  not null,
    CodTipoAposta not null references TipoAposta(CodTipoAposta),
    CodEstadoAposta varchar2(1) default '0' references EstadoAposta(CodEstadoAposta) 
);
```

Note that the types need to be declared for columns when there are foreign key references.  I also put the foreign key reference as the last condition on the column.

Comment: It seems that the column `default` clause has a dependency on the datatype definition, although I couldn't see this explicitly stated in the documentation (syntax railroad diagrams etc). Otherwise the datatype can be allowed to inherit from the parent as for `CodTipoAposta`. Also if on 12.1 or later, I find `default on null` an improvement (and it implicitly sets the column `not null`).

Answer (score 1):

I ran this through Postgresql, slightly modified for Postgres types, to get a better diagnostic.

```
test=> CREATE TABLE Aposta (
test(>     CodAposta decimal(10) Primary key,
test(>     data DATE default sysdate not null,
test(>     hora varchar(5) not null, 
test(>     valor decimal(10,2) not null,
test(>     quotaTotal decimal(10,2)  not null,
test(>     CodTipoAposta references TipoAposta(CodTipoAposta) not null,
test(>     CodEstadoAposta references EstadoAposta(CodEstadoAposta) default '0' not null
test(> );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "references"
LINE 7:     CodTipoAposta references TipoAposta(CodTipoAposta) not n...
```

Each column needs a name, type, and optional constraints. `references ...` is a constraint. It's missing the type which should match the type of the column it's referencing.

In addition, Oracle appears to be [***extremely*** particular about the order of constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE). `default` must appear after the type and before any constraints.

[image]

```
CodTipoAposta number (1) not null references TipoAposta(CodTipoAposta),
CodEstadoAposta number(1) default '0' not null references EstadoAposta(CodEstadoAposta)
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1dacb8810bad53ef0ad513c4c4272f42).

It seems Oracle strictly follows the [SQL standard grammar for a column definition](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2011-foundation-grammar.html#_11_4_column_definition) where `default` is separate from column constraints like `references` and `not null`. Most SQL implementations use a more relaxed grammar where `default` is considered a column constraint.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. The image in the thread edit still appears. Maybe that is just a PostgreSQL thing.

Comment: @LyZ4RD It's the missing types, but also Oracle appears to be EXTREMELY particular about the order of its constraints. It seems `default` has to come immediately after the type.

Answer (score 1):

Data Types is required for all columns: e.g.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Aposta (
>     CodAposta Number(10) PRIMARY KEY
>   , data date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL
>   , hora VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL
>   , valor Number(10, 2) NOT NULL
>   , quotaTotal Number(10, 2) NOT NULL
>   , CodTipoAposta number(1) NOT NULL --references TipoAposta(CodTipoAposta)
>   , CodEstadoAposta number(1) DEFAULT 0 --references EstadoAposta(CodEstadoAposta) 
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51db178492fbf53333b27c17629ad94f)*

the references are commented because I don't have those tables, aso the data atyoes used may be incorrect